# How to append the grand-parent folder name to the filename?

Tags: python

I have directory where multiple folders exist and within each folder,a file exist inside another folder. Below is the structure

```
C:\users\TPCL\New\20190919_xz.txt
C:\users\TPCH\New\20190919_abc.txt
```

**Objective:**

I want to rename the file names like below:

```
C:\users\TPCL\New\20190919_xz_TPCL.txt
C:\users\TPCH\New\20190919_abc_TPCH.txt
```

My Approach:

```
for root,dirs,filename in os.walk('C\users\TPCL\New'):
     prefix = os.path.basename(root)
     for f in filename:
         os.rename(os.path.join(root,f),os.path.join(root,"{}_{}".format(f,prefix)))
```

The above approach is yielding the following result:

```
C:\users\TPCL\New\20190919_xz_New.txt
C:\users\TPCH\New\20190919_abc_New.txt
```

So the question is: How to get the grand-parent folder name get appended, instead of parent folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both dirname and basename to do this.

Use os.path.dirname to get the directory name (excluding the last part) and  
then use os.path.basename to get the last part of the pathname.

Replace 
`prefix = os.path.basename(root)`

with

```
os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(root))
```

Please refer this: 

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname

Answer (score 1):

Using `PurePath` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) you can get the parts of the path. If the path contains the filename its *grand-parent folder* will be at index `-3`.

```
In [23]: from pathlib import PurePath

In [24]: p = r'C:\users\TPCL\New\20190919_xz_TPCL.txt'

In [25]: g = PurePath(p)

In [26]: g.parts
Out[26]: ('C:\\', 'users', 'TPCL', 'New', '20190919_xz_TPCL.txt')

In [27]: g.parts[-3]
Out[27]: 'TPCL'
```

If the path does not contain the filename the *grand=parent* would be at index `-2`.

---

Your process would look something like this:

```
import os.path
from pathlib import PurePath

for root,dirs,fnames in os.walk(topdirectory):
    #print(root)
    try:
        addition = PurePath(root).parts[-2]
        for name in fnames:
            n,ext = os.path.splitext(name)
            newname = n + '_' + addition + ext
            print(name, os.path.join(root,newname))
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

I added the `try/except` to filter out paths that don't have *grand-parents* - it isn't necessary if you know it isn't needed.

Comment: How can I use this for a list of paths? Eg. lets assume `p` is a list of 3 different filepaths.

Comment: Basically you just iterate over the list; make a `PurePath` of each; get/extract the `-3` index of the `PurePath` parts.

Comment: Thats fine. Infact I tried the same. However, I am not able to apply `g.parts()` then.  It shows error as `list object has no attribute 'parts'` similar like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the path string using '\' and then count back to what would be considered the grandparent
 directory for any given file and then append it. For example, if you have

```
filename = "dir1\dir2\file.txt"
splitPaths = filename.split('\') // gives you ['dir1', 'dir2', 'file.txt']
```

the last entry is the file name, the second to last is the parent, and the third to last is the grandparent and so on. You can then append whichever directory you want to the end of the string.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? This is quite a generic statement.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added some detail.